# Is there a way to delay the auto upload of Photos to OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, camera, nokia-lumia-830

Let's say that I took 10 consecutive photos. But I will delete a few bad shots afterwards. But the photos are already being uploaded to OneDrive as its supposed to. Is there a way that to delay the upload? so I dont have to cleanup my OneDrive too.

I dont want to manually upload everytime.
I dont want to switch wifi on/off just to avoid auto upload.

Comment: I'd recommend just uploading full-size images when you're connected to Wi-Fi. This way you can still delete images when you're on a trip before uploading them.

Comment: I don't think, that this problem is OneDrive or Microsoft specific. I've been struggling for over 5 years with Dropbox to enforce them to implement the very same feature. And I failed. It seems, that we can't do nothing about this. "Big People" out there decided, that everything must be pushed immediately. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 2):

Not at this time, it is an all or noting deal. Either you upload right away or you don't.